# How to share session IDs among distributed nginx deployments?

Tags: ssl, nginx, docker

I need to deploy a handful of nginx (with docker). These instances need to share a in memory pool of session IDs so that TLS resumption can take place regardless which instance client connects to. Session tickets with shared key rotation would be great as well.

Ideal answer: docker compose file with nginx and memcache/redis

Comment: You could try using [this](https://github.com/magro/memcached-session-manager/blob/master/samples/nginx.conf) module, which uses memcached as nginx sessions, this way you can have (N) nginx servers/

Comment: @Alin Andrei That’s for Tomcat, not RFC5077.

Comment: Here’s how stud (deprecated) did it https://www.haproxy.com/blog/scaling-out-ssl/

Comment: nghttp2’s nghttpx replicated it https://github.com/nghttp2/nghttp2

Comment: Apache httpd also didn’t get it. https://journal.paul.querna.org/articles/2010/07/10/overclocking-mod_ssl/

Answer (score 0):

It’s available as 3rd-party modules and Lua code as part of OpenResty

https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-core/blob/master/lib/ngx/ssl/session.md